# referencing images in SweetAlert2 modals in vue

Tags: vue.js, sweetalert2

I have a sweetAlert2 modal and I wanted to use an image inside it but either I reference an img like this
src="./assets/img/cry.png"   or  src="../assets/img/cry.png"  it will not show up but in other parts of vue this src addresses works fine, how should I reference it in SweetAlert2?

```
 this.$swal({
 title: '<div style="font-weight:bold;">sorry</div>',
 icon: 'error',
 confirmButtonText: 'Cool',
 position: 'top',
 backdrop: false,
 html:'<img  src="../assets/img/cry.png" style="width:128px;height:128px;">',
 })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is solved like this:

```
const imagePath = require("@/assets/img/cry.png");

this.$swal({
title: '<div style="font-weight:bold;">sorry</div>',
showConfirmButton: false,
backdrop: false,
imageUrl: imagePath,
imageWidth: 100,
imageHeight: 100,
});
```

Comment: but i would like to put on html: "maintenance <img/>" 
the imageUrl is only appears on top of the title swall. did u know how ? ```this.$swal({
              title: '',
              html: web_msg,```